# Undocumented Members of TPropInfo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

System.TypInfo.TPropInfo has two function members (at least in D-XE3):

```
function NameFld: TTypeInfoFieldAccessor; inline;
function Tail: PPropInfo; inline;
```

I cannot find any documentation for them or any examples of their use. What are they for and how can they be used? (Hope that qualifies as one question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NameFld function returns the name of a property as a `TTypeInfoFieldAccessor`.

This allows you to do the following:

```
MyPropertyName:= MyPropInfo.NameFld.ToString;
if (PropInfoA.NameFld = PropInfoB.NameFld) then begin 
  writeln('property names are the same');
end;
```

The TTypeInfoFieldAccessor stores the name of a property in a [shortstring](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.ShortString) internally.
Because the NextGen compiler does not support shortstrings, a `PByte` type is used.
<sub>(I guess the author did not want to litter the source with ifdefs and ripped out the PShortstring references)</sub>

The input of `Tail` is a PByte pointing to length field of the internal shortstring.

Here's the source code for tail.

```
function TTypeInfoFieldAccessor.Tail: PByte;
begin
  Result:= 
    FData    //Start of the shortstring 
    + FData^ + //Length of the stringData
    + 1; //Add one for the length byte itself
end;
```

Because shortstrings are not null terminated, you cannot do a simple "loop until the null char is found" kind of loop.
Therefore a loop from start to tail can employed to transfer the shortstring into a normal string.
Strangely enough in the actual RTL sourcecode the length byte is used everywhere instead of the `tail` function; so it looks like a leftover.
It would have made more sense to include a `size` function and rip out the `tail`.