# How can we manipulate (in RTTI) Name property of TPropInfo when compiling with NEXTGEN compiler?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

### Overview

I want to check if the property name is 'caption' or 'text'. In windows or OSX if do this by comparing the string.

```
if (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name = 'Caption') or (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name = 'Text') then
```

When compiling for mobile, I've found that using NEXTGEN compiler, the name property is no longer a ShortString but a Byte.

If I look at the `Name` property of `TPropInfo` in `System.TypInfo`, `Name : TSymbolName` :

```
type
{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
  TSymbolName = Byte;
{$ELSE  NEXTGEN}
  TSymbolNameBase = string[255];
  TSymbolName = type TSymbolNameBase;
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}
```

Then I can not now compare with string 'text' or 'caption' directly. I've tried to convert 'text' and 'caption' string to array of Byte :

### Code Snippet

```
 var
    PListe : PPropList;
    IdxProp: Integer;
    NbProps: Integer;
    strTmp, sPropName : string;

{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
    BinarySize: Integer;
    InputString: string;
    StringAsBytes_Caption: array of Byte;
    StringAsBytes_Text: array of Byte;
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}

  Begin
    New(PListe);
    NbProps := GetPropList(PTypeInfo(AComp.ClassInfo), tkProperties, PListe);    //tkAny   //tkProperties

{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
    InputString := 'Caption';
    BinarySize := (Length(InputString) + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
    SetLength(StringAsBytes_Caption, BinarySize);
    Move(InputString[1], StringAsBytes_Caption[0], BinarySize);

    InputString := 'Text';
    BinarySize := (Length(InputString) + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
    SetLength(StringAsBytes_Text, BinarySize);
    Move(InputString[1], StringAsBytes_Text[0], BinarySize);
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}

    for IdxProp := 0 to NbProps - 1 do
    begin

{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
    //todo: we need to compare if (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name) is 'caption' or 'text'
    //  but not working     
    if (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name = StringAsBytes_Caption[0]) or (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name = StringAsBytes_Text[0]) then
{$ELSE  NEXTGEN}
     if (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name = 'Caption') or (PListe^[IdxProp]^.Name = 'Text') then
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}
     begin
    ...
     end;
```

### Question

How can I compare the (zero-base string) Name define as a Byte by the NEXTGEN define ?

Comment: See [Undocumented Members of TPropInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15832975/576719)

Comment: Or consider switching to using modern RTTI from the `System.Rtti` unit instead of using legacy RTTI from the `Sysyem.TypInfo` unit.

Comment: Wrong question: the correct one would be "How can I get the Name as string on NEXTGEN?" which is being answered in the link that @LURD posted.