# Unit name from class type stopped working

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have this function which has been working for a long time, but it suddenly stopped when I compiled the unit in a new project. I think it might be because the new project is an FMX one and the resulting type is different.

```
class function TUnit.UnitName(aClassInfo: Pointer): String;
var
  TD: PTypeData;
begin
  Result := '';
  TD := GetTypeData(aClassInfo);
  if TD <> nil then
    Result := TD^.UnitName;
end;
```

I am now getting the error
[dcc32 Error] E1057 Implicit string cast from 'TSymbolName' to 'string'
When I look in System.TypInfo I see this for the type definition

```
{$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
  TSymbolName = Byte;
{$ELSE  NEXTGEN}
  TSymbolNameBase = string[255];
  TSymbolName = type TSymbolNameBase;
{$ENDIF NEXTGEN}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with FMX.  RTTI is implemented in the core RTL and is shared with both VCL and FMX. You are simply assigning a `ShortString` (an ANSI type) directly to a `UnicodeString`, so an implicit data type conversion is performed, hence the warning.  Just use an explicit type-cast to get rid of the warning: `Result := String(TD^.UnitName);`

Comment: @Remy It's not a warning. It's an error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Only because the project settings make it an error instead of a warning. That doesn't change what I said overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With default project settings, this code would generate a compiler warning, [W1057](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/W1057_Implicit_string_cast_from_%27%25s%27_to_%27%25s%27_(Delphi)). This is documented like so:

> #### W1057 Implicit string cast from '%s' to '%s' (Delphi)
>
> Emitted when the compiler detects a case where it must implicitly
>   convert an AnsiString (or AnsiChar) to some form of Unicode (a
>   UnicodeString or a WideString). This warning is on by default.
>
> To avoid this warning, you need to explicitly typecast your AnsiString
>   to the new string type (UnicodeString), as follows:
>
> ```
> <your_target_string> := string(<your_ansi_source);
> ```
>
> The warning is also given for assigning a UTF8String value to an
>   instance of UnicodeString or WideString, in which case you can use an
>   explicit cast to UTF8String.

Your project is configured such that W1057 is treated as an error. Hence it is promoted to E1057 and this code results in a compiler error, as opposed to a warning. This setting can be configured in code, or in the *Project Options* dialog, under the *Hints and Warnings* page.

You have two solutions:

1. Change the project options so that this condition is either ignored, or is treated as a warning.
2. Use an explicit cast as described above.

The second option is usually preferable. That looks like this:

```
Result := string(TD^.UnitName);
```

Comment: `Result := TD^.UnitNameFld.ToString;` works on both platforms. See [Undocumented Members of TPropInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15832975/576719).